# Angularjs: custom two-way binding attribute directive

Tags: angularjs, binding, scope, attributes, directive

I have to write a directive that would have the following behavior :

Controller:

```
vm.mymodel = 'Hello World'
```

Html:

```
<custom-input mydirective="{propbind: 'data-value', propmodel: vm.mymodel}"></custom-input>
```

I would like my custom-input to be transformed as follow:

```
<custom-input data-value="{{vm.mymodel}}"></custom-input>
```

- When I update vm.mymodel from the controller, the data-value attribute has to change.
- When I update the data-value, the vm.mymodel has to be updated too.
- I can't use ng-mmodel directive on the custom-input (it uses data-value, and has internal functions applied to it)

So here's what I tried to do :

- In the compile function of my directive, set scope.propbind attribute value to "{{propmodel}}", then remove "mydirective" attribute. But I don't seem to have access to the scope here. However, if I use element.attr('data-value', 'hello world') I can see my data-value correctly set
- I tried to do the same in the link function, but my scope's values are undefined
- I also tried in the controller function, but my scope is also empty, plus I don't have access to attr or element.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  this.mymodel = 'Hello world !';
});

app.directive('mydirective', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
          bindingvalue: '='
        },
        compile: function(element) {
          //remove the element for clarity
          element.removeAttr('mydirective'); 
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
          //set the attribute
          attr.$set($scope.bindingvalue.propbind, $scope.bindingvalue.propmodel);
          //Observe the attribute value for changes
          attr.$observe($scope.bindingvalue.propbind, function(value) {
            $scope.bindingvalue.propmodel = value;
          })
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
          //Nothing here yet
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl as vm">
  <input mydirective="{propbind: 'data-value', propmodel: vm.mymodel}" type="text"/>
  model value : {{vm.mymodel}}
</div>
```

Can you please help me ? Is my logic good for my problem ? I think that if I manage to get my scope values in my link function, everythink could work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. Here's my solution :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.mymodel = 'Hello world !';
  vm.changeModel = function() {
    vm.mymodel = 'New Value'
    console.log(document.getElementById('myinput'))
  }
  vm.changeAttribute = function() {
    document.getElementById('myinput').setAttribute('data-value', '123456789');
    console.log(document.getElementById('myinput'))
  }
});

app.directive('mydirective', function ($timeout, $interval) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    transclude: false,
    scope: {
      propbind: '@',
      model: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      attr.$set(scope.propbind, scope.model);

      //Watch model for changes, and update attribute
      scope.$watch(function () {
        return scope.model
      }, function () {
        attr.$set(scope.propbind, scope.model);
      });

      //Watch for changes in attribute, and update model
      scope.$watch(function () {
        return elem[0].getAttribute(scope.propbind);
      }, function (value) {
        $timeout(function () {
          scope.model = value;
        });
      });

      //Get attribute value for angularjs to reevaluate dom
      $interval(function () {
        var val = elem[0].getAttribute(scope.propbind)
      }, 100);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl as vm">
  <input id="myinput" mydirective propbind="data-value" model="vm.mymodel" type="text"/>
  model value : {{vm.mymodel}}
  <div>
  <button ng-click="vm.changeModel()">change model value</button>
  <button ng-click="vm.changeAttribute()">change model value</button>
  </div>
  {{document.getElementById('myinput')}}
</div>
```

The demo uses a basic input instead of my custom input, so it is not actually bind to the data-value attribute.
However, you can click the two buttons to update the model in the controller, or the data-value attribute.
You can see that if I change the value in my controller, the data-value gets updated.
Also, if you update the data-value of the input, the model gets updated in the controler.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.mymodel = 'Hello world !';
});

app.directive('customInput', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          value: '='
        },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="value" />',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
          //Nothing here yet
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl as vm">
  <custom-input data-value="vm.mymodel"> </custom-input>
  model value : {{vm.mymodel}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I have to use the custom-input with its data-value. Your solution would replace my custom-input by a basic input linked with ng-model, right ?

Comment: I would like to, but I can't. It is a custom library of webcomponent which I don't have access to the sources. As the custom-input actually creates multiples div, I cannot just add a ng-model property (it would be placed on the top div instead of the actual input element). Plus there is a custom validation mechanism built in, but everything is based on the data-value attribute. I'm not sure if it is very clear, I struggle to explain it in english, sorry